# "element not visible " cant get the element while user logged in protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, element, protractor

I have weird problem with protractor.

In the page I can get element (its bonded to google address service) when user not logged I can get the element ,but if I sign up in my website  and come back to same  page, it say's element not visible.

Here is my element:

```
<input id="input" type="" ng-change="changedInputLocation()" class="form-control addressHr input_width_d ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-attr-placeholder="{{bookingWidgetLanguage.txtWatermarkPickupAddress}}" name="addressHr" ng-autocomplete="" ng-model="addressHr" details="geoAddressHr" placeholder="PICKUP ADDRESS" autocomplete="off">
```

I used code below to grab the element:

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-model="addressHr"]')).sendKeys(' Wilshire Boulevard, Los Angeles, CA, United States', protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Probably same element is not actually visible and the element you want is a different one

Answer (score 1):

We can only make guesses in this case, but here is an educated one: *wait for the element to become visible before interacting with it*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.model('addressHr'));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elm), 5000);
```

Also, note that I'm using `element()` instead of `element.all()` and [`by.model()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model) locator.